# Method invocation error while working with HttpWebRequest\Response in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest, adfs, httpwebresponse

I have a POSH script which executes a set of steps (functions) to instantiate a request to ADFS server, logs into it using default credentials, parses the response and in the end posts secure data to `/_trust/` endpoint on SharePoint server to obtain the FedAuth cookie.

That's for the sake of accessing the specific SharePoint site.

I will omit the details, in fact, the script was working a few weeks ago and now it showed me an error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Boolean] does not contain a method named 'GetResponse'.
At XXXXXX.ps1:48 char:5
+     [System.Net.HttpWebResponse]$response = $request.GetResponse()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

The line the error output refers to is the following:

```
    [System.Net.HttpWebResponse]$response = $request.GetResponse()
```

The important part of the script (which is responsible for the code above) is:

```
function GetADFSRequest {

    $url =  ($adfsUrl+$wia+"wa="+$wa+'&'+"wtrealm="+$wtrealm+'&'+"wctx="+$wctx+'&'+"wreply="+$wreply)
    $address = New-Object System.Uri($url)
    [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($address)
    $request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    $request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3")
    $request.Method = "GET"
    $request.Host = $adfsUrl.TrimStart("https://").TrimEnd("/adfs/ls")
    $request.UseDefaultCredentials;

    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

    return $request
}

function GetADFSResponse($request) {

   $request = GetADFSRequest

    [System.Net.HttpWebResponse]$response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($response.GetResponseStream())
    $obj = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
```

Of course, the required assemblies like `System.Web` or `System.Net` are loaded in the script body.

I have a suggestion that this can be related to a recent ADFS server upgrade (v. 2012 to v. 2016) however, I have no idea why the casting\type conversion error is shown.

When checked via debug mode, the following is displayed:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\temp>> $request | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Net.HttpWebRequest

Name                                 MemberType Definition                                                                                                               
----                                 ---------- ----------                                                                                                               
Abort                                Method     void Abort()                                                                                                             
AddRange                             Method     void AddRange(int from, int to), void AddRange(long from, long to), void AddRange(int range), void AddRange(long range...
```

which means the `$request` type is set correctly using `[System.Net.HttpWebRequest]$request` statement.

Indeed, when performing the same check under `$response` type the error is shown:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\temp>> $response | gm
gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:13
+ $response | gm
+             ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand
```

which is explainable because of the aforementioned error (`[System.Boolean]`, which is, in this case, the `$request` variable does not have a method `"GetResponse"`).

Comment: The line `$request.UseDefaultCredentials;` returns $false. This will be returned from GetADFSRequest. I think you want to set the value to something, not read it.

Comment: i.e. `$request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true` or `$request.UseDefaultCredentials = $false`

Comment: Thank you, but it was intentionally set to $ false (as a default behavior). I've tried setting it to $ true also, and on a par with the following piece of code: `$ request.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache] :: DefaultCredentials`, alas it does not work too.